# How to "export" functions in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, bash-functions

I have a script, which has a lot of functions inside.

myfile1.sh:

```
func1() {}

func2() {}
```

I can call them from script with:

myfile2.sh:

```
source myfile1.sh

func1

func2
```

But how can I call them if sourced in nested script?

myfile3.sh:

```
./myfile2.sh

func2

func2: command not found
```

Can I "export" functions from `myfile2` so that everybody knew them?

I can't use `export -f` because there are many functions.

Comment: I'm assuming that running `myfile3.sh` recursively is a typo?  You also know that there is _no way_ to export anything to a parent or sibling process?

Comment: I can export variables, can't I?

Comment: @Dims not to a parent shell.

Comment: @muru then how can I set variables in `bashrc` or any other scripts? They should be confined inside them.

Comment: @Dims `.bashrc` is *sourced*, not executed as a script, so the commands in it are executed in the current shell.

Comment: @muru wow, that's incredible, I didn't knew this; how long ago the notion of "sourced" appeared in Linux?

If scripts are "sourced", then why should I use `export` command at all? variables should remain w/o `export` too?

Comment: @Dims Not everything you run is a script written for your particular shell, so you can't source everything all the time. For example, the `mktemp` utility is not a script that you can source, yet it examines its environment for the value of the `TMPDIR` variable. If that variable wasn't exported, you would have to use other means to create temporary files in a specific directory (just as an example).

Answer (score 4):

Note that `bash` is not `sh`. `export -f` is specific to the `bash` shell.

If a script doesn't have a she-bang, it will be interpreted by a POSIX-like shell which may not be bash. If you intend to use `bash`-specific features in your script, you should make sure it has a:

```
#! /path/to/bash -
```

she-bang or that you invoke it as `bash path/to/the/script`. Also giving `.sh` extensions to scripts written in the `bash` language is a bit misleading.

Now `bash` is one of those few shells which are able to export functions to the environment (in effect using special environment variables understood by `bash` commands only). It can be done using the `export -f` bash-specific command. `bash` also exports all functions that are declared whilst the `allexport` option is on.

But in any case, neither of those would work in your case. `export`ing something from one shell, whether it's a variable or function, is so that that variable/function is available in other shells that that shell *executes* (exporting is about preserving things across *execution*).

So even if the `myfile1.sh` or `myfile2.sh` exported the functions they declared (with `export -f` or by having a `set -o allexport` before the variable declaration), that would only affect the shells that the shell interpreting those scripts would execute. Here `myfile2.sh` is not executing `myfile3.sh`, it's the other way round.

Here you'd need your `myfile3.sh` script to do:

```
source path/to/myfile2.sh
```

so that it's the same shell that interprets the code in all of the `myfile1.sh`, `myfile2.sh` and `myfile3.sh` scripts, and then you wouldn't need to export any function.

Note that on systems where `sh` is `bash`, it's probably not a good idea to export functions, as that affects all sh and bash scripts and shell command lines that your script executes (recursively). For instance, if you did:

```
set -o allexport
uname() { echo Gotcha; }
somecmd
```

And `somecmd` was doing a `popen("uname", "r")` to get the unix name, it would get `Gotcha` on systems where `sh` is `bash` instead of the real name of the system (`Darwin`, `Linux`...).